# MS Word macro to delete all empty paragraphs leaving sections interruptions

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm written this macro in MS Word to remove all empty paragraphs.
It works well but, if document contains more than one section, the macro deletes the interruption and merges all sections into one.

```
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
    For i = .Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Len(.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text) = 1 Then
            .Paragraphs(i).Range.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: For each mySection in ActiveDocument.Sections......for each MyPara in mySection,Paragraphs or something similar.  Just don't delete the last paragraph in a Section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your document has tables preceded by empty paragraphs, you don't even need VBA for this! All you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = [^13]{2,}
Replace = ^p
```

Of course, this could be incorporated into a macro, with code like:

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[^13]{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False 
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

In case you do have tables preceded by empty paragraphs, see:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/167142-post9.html

Comment: I've tried yet, but it works on MS Word 2016, not on MS Word 2019.
MS Word doesn't recognize "[^13]{2,}" as string to replace.

Comment: The F/R expression works on *all* Word versions. If it's not working on a particular installation for you, that will be because that installation has non-English regional settings. In that case, change the {2,} to {2;}

Comment: You are right @macropod
The expression works on all Word versions which have english regional settings.
Replacing "," with ";" it works on a Word version which has italian regional settings.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Replace

```
Sub ReplaceEmptyParagraphs()
    ' https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DeleteEmptyParas.htm by Word MVP Dave Rado
    ' this procedure compiled from above by Charles Kenyon 6/29/2021
    '   IN GENERAL - EMPTY PARAGRAPHS
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^13{2,}"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    '   FIRST AND LAST EMPTY PARAGRAPHS
    Dim MyRange As range
    Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).range
    If MyRange.Text = vbCr Then MyRange.Delete

    Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Last.range
    If MyRange.Text = vbCr Then MyRange.Delete

    '   BEFORE AND AFTER TABLES
    Dim oTable As Table

    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
        #If VBA6 Then
            'The following is only compiled and run if Word 2000 or 2002 is in use
            'It speeds up the table and your code
            oTable.AllowAutoFit = False
        #End If

        'Set a range to the para following the current table
        Set MyRange = oTable.range
        MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        'if para after table empty, delete it
        If MyRange.Paragraphs(1).range.Text = vbCr Then
            MyRange.Paragraphs(1).range.Delete
        End If

        'Set a range to the para preceding the current table
        Set MyRange = oTable.range
        MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        MyRange.Move wdParagraph, -1
        'if para before table empty, delete it
        If MyRange.Paragraphs(1).range.Text = vbCr Then
            MyRange.Paragraphs(1).range.Delete
        End If
    Next oTable
    Set MyRange = Nothing
    Set oTable = Nothing
End Sub
```

See [Remove all empty paragraphs from a document](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DeleteEmptyParas.htm) by Word MVP Dave Rado. See the full article.

> You can remove most empty paragraphs from a document by doing a
> wildcard Find & Replace.

Comment: I've tried yet, but it works on MS Word 2016, not on MS Word 2019.
MS Word doesn't recognize "[^13]{2,}" as string to replace.

Comment: This works in Word 2003, Word 2007, Word 2010, Word 2013, Word 2016, Word 2019, Word 2021, and Word 365. I think it works in Word 97, 2000, and 2002 as well. Something is wrong with your installation if it was typed properly. Did you read the linked article by Dave Rado? *Paul Edstein (macropod) knows wild card searches far better than I.*

Comment: You are right
The expression works on all Word versions which have english regional settings.
Replacing "," with ";" it works on a Word version which has italian regional settings.
Thank you for calling macropod in this thread.